# "Variable-sized object may not be initialized" - what does this mean, and why am I getting this type of error?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, variable-length-array

```cpp
vector<string> commonChars(vector<string>& words) {
    int count[words.size()][26] = {}; 
    //getting error 
    //error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

    string ele;
    vector<string> result;
    for(int s1=0; s1<words.size(); s1++){
        for(int s2=0; s2<words[s1].size(); s2++){
            count[s1][words[s1][s2]-97]++;
        }
    }
    for(int s=0; s<26; s++){
        int small = count[0][s];
        for(int i=1; i<words.size(); i++){
            small = min(small, count[i][s]);
        }
        while(small-- > 0){
            ele = (char)(s+97);
            result.push_back(ele);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

On the line `int count[words.size()][26] = {};`

> error: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Can anyone help me? What is this error?

Comment: Variable length arrays like `int count[words.size()]` are a non-standard compiler extension.  `count` should probably be a `vector<int>` instead.

Comment: I recommend upgrading your compiler. That issue was resolved in GCC 4.9 and the cool kids are using GCC 11.1 these days. In GCC 4.8 and earlier variable length arrays did not zero initialize.

Comment: @0x5453 or, in this case, a `std::vector<std::array<int,26>>` instead.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, that's a compiler extension of a compiler extension: https://godbolt.org/z/xY6dnsze3

Comment: Well well welly well. When I was playing with this yesterday I didn't specify the Standard. Looks like there are many shades to this bit of non-Standard mess. I'm just going to stick with not using the damn things.

Comment: Wait a second. One of those is using a C compiler. No fair!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int count[words.size()][26] = {};
```

declares a variable length array because the value of the expression `words.size()` is not a compile time constant.

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. It seems that the used compiler has its own language extension that allows to use VLAs.

Nevertheless you may not initialize such an array in its declaration.

So you need to write

```
int count[words.size()][26];
```

Then you can use for example either the C function `memset` or a standard algorithm like `std::fill` or `std::generate` to initialize the array.

In fact there is no need to declare a two-dimensional variable length array in your function. At least you could use a one-dimensional array like

```
int count[26] = {};
```

and use it for processing each string in the vector.

But it would be even better to use the standard container `std::map<char, size_t>` instead of the array.